# Make (io.Reader).Read wait for all the bytes to be present

Tags: go, upload

I'm trying to implement a real-time uploading proxy which should take the input raw binary data and forward it into chunks of 250MB each to an external server

I'm currently using [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) as the web framework, and [go-resty](https://github.com/go-resty/resty) as the HTTP client handling the upload to the external server

What I have at the moment is:

```golang
func chunker(rc io.ReadCloser, bytes int64) ([]byte, int64, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, bytes)
    n, err := rc.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte(""), 0, err
    }
    return buf[:n], int64(n), nil
}

func Upload(c *gin.Context) {
    w := c.Writer
    req := c.Request
    reqBody := req.Body
    reqBodySize := int64(req.ContentLength)
    bytesPerChunk := int64(262144000) // 250 MB

    for {
        var noOfBytes int64 = bytesPerChunk
        if reqBodySize < bytesPerChunk {
            noOfBytes = reqBodySize
        }
        noOfBytes -= 1 // (io.ReadCloser).Read always returns an EOF error if we don't subtract one byte of the total (which is the normal & expected behavior of file uploads by the way)
        if noOfBytes <= 0 {
            break
        }

        bytes, size, err := chunker(reqBody, noOfBytes)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("body EOF")
            break
        }
        reqBodySize -= size

        upload, _, err := external.Upload(bytes)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteString("an error has occured")
            return
        }
    }

    reqBody.Close()
    w.WriteString("upload complete")
}
```

Now the issue, is that since the whole process is happening in real time, `rc.Read(buf)` won't wait till the uploader has finished sending their first 250 MB before jumping to the next chunk

After referring to https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader, I found out that this is the normal behavior of `Read`:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the call. **If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.**

Is there any way to make `Read` wait for the specified bytes count to be available instead of using the sent-so-far in the `io.ReadCloser` instance?

Comment: No. If you need to read asynchronously, you can do that. In practice there is no way to know how long it will take, and the underlying syscall is going to return whenever there is _something_ ready. Otherwise use [`io.ReadFull`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadFull)

Comment: You don't need to allocate a new buffer for ever read if you are uploading synchronously. Your `chunker` error handling is also incorrect, you will miss any bytes read with EOF.

Comment: @JimB - Thank you for stopping by :) I know my error handling is still incomplete, that's something I'll get to as soon as I finish the essential bits first. Do you mean using something like `n, err := io.ReadFull(rc, buf)` instead of `rc.Read(buf)`? Will `ReadFull` behave like `Read` and not start over from the first byte on every call?

Comment: The io.ReadFull helper function calls Read in a loop until the buffer is filled or an error is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

To finalize this question and get it answered (there still can be better approaches, will appreciate whoever can share them with us)

As stated by @JimB in the comments, [`io.ReadFull`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadFull) is what I should use to wait for the specified count of bytes to be ready before moving to the next bit of code

So the `chunker` function should be like:

```golang
func chunker(rc io.ReadCloser, bytes int64) ([]byte, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, bytes)
    n, err := io.ReadFull(rc, buf)
    return buf[:n], err
}
```

Comment: Because the length of the returned slice is always equal to the count return value, the count return value is not needed.  See https://go.dev/play/p/VQAL4IdGpez for a simplification of the code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - Keeping it like that, in my opinion, is better since `ReadFull` will return it anyway. feels more efficient than using `len` on the outputted bytes

Comment: It's doubtful that returning the length in two values is more efficient than returning the length in one value. The built in `len` function compiles to a field access in the slice header.